# Bitnami Rails Godaddy, need help deploying Ruby On Rails application on GoDaddy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting, bitnami, godaddy-api

I am using bitnami rails image of cloud server of godaddy, I have accessed the Files through filezilla. Please can anyone tell where to copy the code of my project so that people access it through domain public IP. I dont know in which folder to copy the code of my project.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested place where put your code is `/home/bitnami/YOURAPP`.

After create your APP you may want to configure Apache with Passenger in order to server it in a production environment.

Create a new file at `/home/bitnami/httpd-vhosts.conf` with this content:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName HOST_NAME
   DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/YOURAPP/public/"
    <Directory "/home/bitnami/YOURAPP/public/">
        Options -MultiViews
        <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        RailsEnv development
        PassengerEnabled on
        PassengerAppRoot "/home/bitnami/YOURAPP/"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Replace the HOST_NAME placeholder with the host name of your cloud server and the `/home/bitnami/YOURAPP` path with the correct path to your Rails application.

Edit the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf file and add the following line to the end of the file:

`Include /home/bitnami/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Restart Apache

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Take care you may need to adjust permission/ownership of your app directory in order to match Bitnami, i.e. `sudo chown bitnami:daemon /home/bitnami/YOURAPP`